# Why is my browser preventing me from submitting empty fields ? Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, required-field

I made a form that allows users to register.

There is one question that asks what language they want to learn. In order to make the question optional I created the new field type to my User entity in Terminal and I specified that it can be **null**.

But, when I validate the form without answering the optional question, I have this displayed error message : **Please select a valid language.**

Thank you for your help.

**register.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Incris-toi !{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

{{ form_start(userform) }}

    <div class="form container">

        {{ form_errors(userform.email) }}
        {{ form_errors(userform.password) }}
        {{ form_errors(userform.gender) }}
        {{ form_errors(userform.firstname) }}
        {{ form_errors(userform.lastname) }}
        {{ form_errors(userform.birthdate) }}
        {{ form_errors(userform.occupation) }}
        {{ form_errors(userform.nationality) }}
        {{ form_errors(userform.nativelanguage) }}
        {{ form_errors(userform.wishedlanguages) }}

        <div class="formpage">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{ form_widget(userform.email, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Mon adresse e-mail', 'class' : 'form-control'}}) }}
                {{ form_label(userform.email, 'Mon adresse e-mail', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{ form_widget(userform.password.first, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Mon mot de passe', 'class' : 'form-control'}}) }}
                {{ form_label(userform.password.first, 'Mon mot de passe', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                {{ form_widget(userform.password.second, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Confirmation de mon mot de passe', 'class' : 'form-control'}}) }}
                {{ form_label(userform.password.second, 'Confirmation de mon mot de passe', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-checkbox">
                {{ form_widget(userform.roles) }}
                <span class="checkbox"></span>
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="next btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary mt-4 d-flex mx-auto">Je m'inscris</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formpage">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Es-tu un homme ou une femme ?</p>
                {{ form_widget(userform.gender, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Es-tu un homme ou une femme ?', 'class' : 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{ form_widget(userform.firstname, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Quel est ton prénom ?', 'class' : 'form-control'}}) }}
                {{ form_label(userform.firstname, 'Quel est ton prénom ?', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{ form_widget(userform.lastname, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Quel est ton nom de famille ?', 'class' : 'form-control'}}) }}
                {{ form_label(userform.lastname, 'Quel est ton nom de famille ?', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <p>Quelle est ta date de naissance ?</p>
                {{ form_widget(userform.birthdate) }}
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <button type="button" class="prev btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary mt-4 d-flex align-items-center me-auto">&lt;<span class="previous">Précédent</span></button>
                <button type="button" class="next btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary mt-4 d-flex ms-auto">Suivant</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formpage">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{ form_widget(userform.occupation, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Quelle est ton occupation (ton métier, tes études…) ?', 'class' : 'form-control'}}) }}
                {{ form_label(userform.occupation, 'Quelle est ton occupation (ton métier, tes études…) ?', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>De quel pays es-tu originaire ?</p>
                {{ form_widget(userform.nationality) }}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Quelle est ta langue maternelle ?</p>
                {{ form_widget(userform.nativelanguage) }}
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <button type="button" class="prev btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary mt-4 d-flex align-items-center me-auto">&lt;<span class="previous">Précédent</span></button>
                <button type="button" class="next optional btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary mt-4 d-flex ms-auto">Suivant</button>
                <button class="btn optional-validation btn-lg btn-outline-primary mt-4 d-flex ms-auto">Je valide</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formpage">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Quelle langue souhaites-tu pratiquer ?</p>
                <div class="wishedlanguagelist">
                    {{ form_widget(userform.wishedlanguages, {'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control mb-3'}}) }}
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" class="question-button btn btn-outline-secondary" id="addwishedlanguage">+ Ajouter une langue</button>
                    <button type="button" class="question-button btn btn-outline-secondary" id="removewishedlanguage">- Supprimer la dernière langue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <button type="button" class="prev btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary mt-4 d-flex align-items-center me-auto">&lt;<span class="previous">Précédent</span></button>
                {{ form_row(userform.save, {'attr' : {'class' : 'btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary mt-4 d-flex ms-auto'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

{{ form_end(userform) }}

{% endblock %}

{% block js %}

<script src="../assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

**UserType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\LanguageType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Je suis ...' => '',
                    'un homme' => 'male',
                    'une femme' =>'female',
                    'non-binaire' => 'non-binary'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('birthdate', BirthdayType::class, [
                'placeholder' => [
                    'year' => 'Année', 'month' => 'Mois', 'day' => 'Jour',
                ],
                'choice_translation_domain' => true
            ])
            ->add('occupation')
            ->add('nationality', CountryType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Je choisis un pays',
            ])
            ->add('nativelanguage', LanguageType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Je choisis ta langue maternelle',
            ])
            ->add('wishedlanguages', LanguageType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Je choisis une langue étrangère',
                'empty_data' => [],
                'required' => false,
                'compound' => true,
            ])
            ->add(
                $builder
                    ->get('wishedlanguages')
                    ->setRequired(false)
            )
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false
            ])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Les deux mots de passe doivent être identiques.',
                'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
            ])
            ->add('roles', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'Je m\'inscris uniquement en tant qu\'organisateur.',
                'required' => false,
                'compound' => true,
            ])
            ->add(
                $builder
                    ->get('roles')
                    ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                        function ($arrayAsBool) {
                        return in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $arrayAsBool);
                    },
                        function ($boolAsArray) {
                        return $boolAsArray ? ["ROLE_ADMIN"] : ["ROLE_USER"];
                    }))
            )
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Je valide',
            ])
            ;
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? On which of these fields does the validation fail?

Comment: Hi ! The field wished languages failed the validation.